# Fetching specific image from Camera roll in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Currently I'm using **UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum** to save an image from specific url on tap of particular button. The image is saved successfully.

Now later on i want to retrieve the same image on tap of same button from camera roll album iOS. I don't want to call the url again for the image.

How this result can be achieved using Objective-C?

```
 [[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] downloadImageWithURL:url
                             options:0
                            progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

                            }
                           completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
                               if (image && finished) {
                                   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,self,
                                       @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                                                      nil);
                               }
                           }];
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Use ALAssestLibrary methods instead, and you will have much more control.

Comment: @elio.d - But this library is deprecated from current version of iOS.

Comment: @RohitaxRajguru well deprecated does not mean that you cannot use it. Anyway, use the PhotoFramework that is the replacement.

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya: Added the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save using Photos framework rather than using **UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum**.

**After getting the image save it using Photos Framework like this.**

```
__block PHObjectPlaceholder *placeholderAsset;

    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{

       PHAssetChangeRequest *changeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];
       placeholderAsset = changeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset;

    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"Success");

            // Save Identifier here
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:placeholderAsset.localIdentifier forKey:@"PhotoIdentifier"];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"write error : %@",error);
        }
    }];
```

// **Retrive image using identifier**

```
PHFetchOptions *allPhotosOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
PHFetchResult *allPhotos = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:allPhotosOptions];

[allPhotos enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset   * _Nonnull photoAsset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

    NSString *photoIdentifier = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"PhotoIdentifier"];
    if([photoIdentifier isEqualToString:photoAsset.localIdentifier]){

        [[PHImageManager defaultManager]requestImageForAsset:photoAsset targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info){
            if ([info objectForKey:PHImageErrorKey] == nil && ![[info objectForKey:PHImageResultIsDegradedKey] boolValue]) {

                // image is here as a result parameter
                *stop = YES;
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

You can use any other medium to store Photo identifier, NSUserDefaults is just an example.